# How to delete the first row

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have some trouble with Laravel SQL builder. I want to delete the first row. I am using the below code:

```
DB::table('ahah')->first()->delete().
```

In the controller, I've already imported `DB` class using the statement `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB`. Can you tell me what's the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: What's the error or problem while deleting ?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work because `DB::table('ahah')->first()` is returning a `stdClass` object. And of course, `stdClass` has no `delete()` method.

So you will need to get the first item of your table with SQL statements:

```php
// Supposing your primary key column is called 'id'

DB::table('ahah')
    ->orderBy('id')
    ->limit(1)
    ->delete();
```

Answer (score 2):

If are working in Laravel then it's better to use **Eloquent ORM** by creating Model.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{

    // Code Stuff
}
```

**fetch the first records and delete**

```
$user = \App\Models\User::orderBy('id')->first()->delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

ModelName: Change with your model

```
$item = ModelName::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->first();
$item->delete();
```

Comment: You will delete the last item if you use a `DESC` order.

Answer (score 0):

As others answered, your requirement should be fulfilled as you described in your question.

I'm just adding a cleaner technique to delete the FIRST row of the table. Create the model (made using Eloquent), then add a scope method which will return the first row of the table and then you just need to call `delete()` on the query builder.

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class FooBarModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'foo_bar';

    /**
     * Scope a query to retrieve first row.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeFirstRow($query)
    {
        return $query->orderBy('id')->first();  // Assuming id is the name of primary key column in the table
    }
}
```

Then you may delete the first row as:

```
FooBarModel::firstRow()->delete();  // This will delete the very first available row every time it is called
```

However, handling the exceptions is always a good practice. Here if no row exists in the table, then calling the above statement will raise an exception as the query builder object will return `null`. So better first check if the result is not null then only call `delete()` method.

```
$firstRow = FooBarModel::firstRow();
if (!is_null($firstRow)) {
    $firstRow->delete();
}
```

Similarly, you can create other scopes as well to delete the last row, last to the last row, etc.

If you want to go for a more cleaner way than this then you can just write a method in the `Model` itself and write all code to delete there.

```
/**
 * @return bool
 */
public static function deleteFirstRow()
{
    $firstRow = self::firstRow();
    if (!is_null($firstRow)) {
        $firstRow->delete();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then call `deleteFirstRow()` to delete first row.

```
FooBarModel::deleteFirstRow();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the oldest method for getting the first record:

```
$ahah_first = \DB::table('ahah')->oldest()->first();
\DB::table('ahah')->where('id', $ahah_first->id)->delete();
```